# Python pandas: Identify Records Based on Multiple Criteria on Multiple Fields

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using IPython (Python 3.4) with pandas: I have a data frame that looks roughly like this (notice the duplicate records per student, sometimes there are 3+ per student):

```
Year    Subject   Student   Score   Date
2014    Math       1        34     31-Jan
2014    Math       1        34     26-Jan
2014    Math       2        65     26-Jan
2014    Math       2        76     31-Jan
2014    Math       3        45     3-Feb
2014    Math       3        67     31-Jan
```

I am looking for a way to return the score per student based on the following criteria:
1. highest score
and when the scores are the same for each of an individual student's records:
2. most recent date

Here's the desired output:

```
Year    Subject   Student   Score   Date
2014    Math       1        34     31-Jan
2014    Math       2        76     31-Jan
2014    Math       3        67     31-Jan
```

Here's what I've tried so far:
Used groupby on year, subject, and student to obtain the highest score per student for a given year and subject area:

```
by_duplicate = df.groupby(['Year', 'Subject', 'Student'])
HighScore = by_duplicate[['Year', 'Subject', 'Student', 'Score']].max()
```

Here, I rename the score column  so that when I join it to the to the original dataframe, I know which column is which. This may not be necessary, but I'm not sure.

```
HighScore.rename(columns={'Score': 'Score2'}, inplace=True)
```

Here, I add a blank 'HighScore' column in anticipation that when it will be populated with a 1 later if the row has the highest score. More on this later...

```
HighScore['HighScore'] = ""
```

Then I do the same for the most recent date:

```
Recent = by_duplicate[['Year', 'Subject', 'Student', 'Date']].max()
Recent.rename(columns={'Date': 'Date2'}, inplace=True)
Recent['Recent'] = ""

My approach was to 
1. create tables for each field (score and date) using groupby, 
2. identify the rows containing the highest and most recent scores, respectively, by entering a "1" in their respective new columns (HighScore' and 'Recent')
3. somehow join these grouped tables back to the original dataframe on Year, Subject, and Student
-I'm guessing this requires somehow ungrouping the groups as the pd.merge is not working on the grouped data frames
4. The end result, according to my theory, would look something like this:

Year    Subject   Student   Score   Date     HighScore  Recent
2014    Math       1        34     31-Jan    1          1   
2014    Math       1        34     26-Jan    1          0
2014    Math       2        65     26-Jan    0          0  
2014    Math       2        76     31-Jan    1          1  
2014    Math       3        45     3-Feb     0          1  
2014    Math       3        67     31-Jan    1          0

And once I have this table, I would need to do something like this:
1. Per student for a given year and subject area: return the sum of 'HighScore'
2. If the sum of 'HighScore' is greater than 1, then take the 'Recent' row equal to 1.
I believe this will give me what I need.
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm following correctly, I think you can simplify this by sorting on both the score and the date, so that the last element of each group is always the most recent of the highest score.  I might do something like

```
>>> df["FullDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Year"].astype(str) + "-" + df["Date"], 
                     format="%Y-%d-%b")
>>> df = df.sort(["Score", "FullDate"])
>>> df.groupby(["Year", "Subject", "Student"]).tail(1)
   Year Subject  Student  Score    Date   FullDate
0  2014    Math        1     34  31-Jan 2014-01-31
5  2014    Math        3     67  31-Jan 2014-01-31
3  2014    Math        2     76  31-Jan 2014-01-31
```

where first I create a `FullDate` column which is a real datetime and not a string, so that I know it'll sort correctly.

Note that the order we sort in matters: we want first by score, and then within the maximum scores the "largest" (most recent) date last.  If instead we had done it the other way, we'd have instead had

```
>>> df = df.sort(["FullDate", "Score"]) # THIS IS THE WRONG ORDER
>>> df.groupby(["Year", "Subject", "Student"]).tail(1)
   Year Subject  Student  Score    Date   FullDate
0  2014    Math        1     34  31-Jan 2014-01-31
3  2014    Math        2     76  31-Jan 2014-01-31
4  2014    Math        3     45   3-Feb 2014-02-03
```

which would give us the maximum score on the latest day.

Now it is true that sorting is ~O(N log N) and finding the maximum can be done in O(N), but IMHO the simplicity dramatically outweighs the usually minor performance loss.

Comment: Genius! I'm not sure what  ~O(N log N) and O(N) mean, but thanks so much! A follow-up question: Will the fact that groupby was used pose problems when I try to append these records to an existing table?